# How to solve this logic?

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I made a test and there was this sequence, as follow:

```
$in = [
[ts->'1', data->'dado 1'];
[ts->'2', data->'dado 2'];
[ts->'3', data->'dado 3'];
]
```

And the follow steps:

1. Filter where ts > x
2. Sort ts
3. Output in Json format (this propably using echo json_encode($in))

How could I solve these steps?

***EDIT***

Maybe it would be an alternative to solve:

```
//Filter ts
function filtrar($in)
{
    $x = 1;
    return($in['ts'] > $x);
}
//Sort ts
foreach ($in as $key => $row) {
    $ts[$key]  = $row['ts'];
}
array_multisort($ts, SORT_ASC, $in);
//output into Json
echo json_encode(array_filter($in, "filtrar"));
```

Comment: What is that format ?

Comment: for the first step, I thought about using "filter_var", but I'm not sure about that. Just about the last step that I believe to be right about using json_encode.

Comment: Take a look at [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thanks, fusion3k. Based on your suggestions, I edited my post with another possible solution (maybe)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have fun :)

```
 $in = [
    ['ts' =>'1', 'data'=>'dado 1'],
    ['ts'=>'2', 'data'=>'dado 2'],
    ['ts'=>'3', 'data'=>'dado 3'],
    ];

    $number = 2;

    $filtered = array_filter($in , function($to_filter) use ($number) {
        if($to_filter['ts'] >= $number)
            return $to_filter;
    });

    print_r($filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a possible solution, after read links suggested:

```
//Filter ts
function filtrar($in)
{
    $x = 1;
    return($in['ts'] > $x);
}
//Sort ts
foreach ($in as $key => $row) {
    $ts[$key]  = $row['ts'];
}
array_multisort($ts, SORT_ASC, $in);
//output into Json
echo json_encode(array_filter($in, "filtrar"));
```

In this links: [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something ? Here is an idea :

```
$buffer = array();
$in = json_decode($in);
foreach ($in as $row)
{
   if ($row['ts'] > 1)
   {
      $buffer[$row['ts']] = $row;
   }
}

ksort($buffer);
var_dump($buffer);
```

Comment: with this line `$in = json_decode($in);` causes error. For the test, I think that makes sense exclude it and include on final `echo json_encode($in);`. What do you think?